# Best practices for configuration files in global (or globally required) variables

Tags: design-patterns, configuration, globals

A common pattern I use on my nontrivial programs is to have a class that parses out a config file (usually YAML), and makes the items in the values in the config available as properties on the class.

I then import this class elsewhere in my program anytime I need to refer to the user-provided configuration

```
#config.yml
app_name: 'Awesome Program'
base_url: 'http://example.com/awesome'
```

---

```
#appconfig.py
import yaml   
class AppConfig(object):
    '''Imports the contents of config.yml as property values'''
    def __init__(self):
        with open('config.yml') as cfgfile:
            y = yaml.load(cfgfile)
            for key in y:
                setattr(self, key, y[key])


CONF = AppConfig()
```

---

```
#app.py
from appconfig import CONF
appname = CONF.app_name
base_url = CONF.base_url
# and so forth
```

However, I've noticed that this tends to make certain IDEs unhappy. PyCharm in particular tends to think this kind of global state (even if it's read only) is strange, yellow-flagging any usage of the CONF variable as a low grade "implicit required file" notice.

A conversation on PyCharm's bug tracker, and a couple other conversations on Hacker News **imply that this is something I shouldn't be doing**.

It's definitely convenient, and hasn't gotten me in trouble yet, but is there a better/more idiomatic/saner way I should be handling this? Note that the configuration is entirely read-only, and so synchronization, locking, and so on are concerns that I'm not worried about.

Comment: Is this just about keeping the IDE and the best-practice zealots happy?  Being "strange" and Hacker News implications are not sufficient reasons to terminate a practice.

Comment: Indeed. But I usually find that IDE warnings and HN users complain about a practice for a very good reason. Hence the question - are these complaints well founded, or just bureaucracy?